# Android how to make a window alert on top view without ask SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

Tags: android, system-alert-window

I would like to make a window alert view on top view by using `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` and when I use my app I need to accept "Draw over Apps" popup.

I downloaded `DU Recorder` app and this application also seems to use this technique but it doesn't show `"Draw over Apps"` popup. Do you know the technique to do the same(DU Recorder) application ? or have we any tricks to do this ? Could you help me to share it ? Thanks so much for your support.

Comment: Are you trying to show an alert on top of the current screen irrespective of which screen the user is in **or** are you trying to record the screen like the DU app. please clarify.